# How to get json data with key in ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to get each result with a key. 
I have a input field in which i am passing the keywords. Here In this Controller i am checking the each keyword for the city, if it Contain a cityname then i will do my stuff. But How can i differentiate both of them with a different key.

Here  **$data** array has city and suggestion key which i want to access this in the ajax.

Like this-

**$data['result]['city'] = ...**

**$data['result]['suggestion'] =**

**Controller**

```
    function autoshow() {
        $data = array('result' => array(),'url' => array(), 'exp' => array());
        $keyword = $this->input->get('search');  
        $search = $this->Mdl_home->get_auto_complete($keyword);

        $explode = explode(' ', $keyword);

        //Here i am checking if keyword has  city name or 
        foreach ($explode as $cityname) {
            $data['result']['city'] = $cityname;
        }

        foreach($search as $row) {
            $usrch[] = $row->service_name;
            $data['result']['suggesition'] = $usrch;
            //Here i am using url to access this in the ajax 
        }

        if (!isset($data)) {
            $data = "";
        }
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Here i am trying to access with the define key name in controller

```
$.each(data.result, function (i, obj) {
 autoData += "<li><a  id='" 
                    + obj['suggesition'] 
                    + "' href='javascript:void(0);'>"
                    + obj['suggesition'] 
                    +(obj['city']) ? obj['city'] : " " 
                    + "</a></li>";
});

autoData += "</ul>";
$("#s_auto").html(autoData);
```

**What i tried:**
 This is giving me undefined. I know there must be some problem in $.each loop.
How to access the key **$obj['key']** in this way ..
I do not know How to do this ..Please see this Code

If i remove **result** from `$.each(data.result, function (i, obj)` from this and simply i can access key **obj['key']** it works but i have multiple type of data in different types. So to access those keys..

If i am doing this is in wrong please tell me. or any type of suggestions Thank you..

This is the result which is showing in the console. After searching "ho" in the keyword

```
{"result":{"city":"","suggesition":"7 Star Hotels"},"suggesition":[]}
```

Comment: can you show the example data of ajax response data  console.log(data);

Comment: i just update my console data

Comment: i think something wrong with data preparation. you should see what exact `$data` results at end. since you looping on `data.result` result should contain array of objects like `{ "result":[{ city:"city1", suggestion:"suggestin" },{ city:"city2", suggestion:"suggestin2" }]}`

Comment: I forgot to remove  `explode`  from i doing something else with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the same `$data['result']['suggesition']` in each iteration.

In order to make the javascript work as written you need something like:

```
foreach($search as $row) {
      $res = array(
             'suggesition'=> $row->service_name,
             'city' => // ?? I don't understand city logic
            );

      // add new item to `$data['result']` array
      $data['result'][] = $res;

}
```

Comment: Thank You.. and i know city logic should not be there. But i'm just asking if i explode the keywords and then if ii run a foreach to find out whether my keywords contains a city name or not.. Is this a right way..

Comment: Possibly, depending on what is sent. You would have to compare each one to something though to validate as a city. Also depends how your database queries are made